# Instantiated GKLocalPlayerListener

Tags: game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

Most turn based match Game Center examples include singeltons, usually called humhumHelper, or something equivalent. Am I looking for trouble if I try do do it in a more dynamic way?

One example is that I register a listener in the init function of a scene (with the scene as listener), and then unregister the scene in the dealloc function. Will this solution have problems if that scene is not active meanwhile the user manipulates the game from the game center app? Someone has stated that GC events are buffered, but in that case, how long?

A related question: How shall this sentence be interpreted?

"Only register a listener a single time. Registering a listener multiple times will result in undefined behavior."(https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/registerListener)

My understanding is that it is ok to have multiple listeners, but that it's not ok to register the same listener twice. What do you think?